# Avoid adding blank new rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, webforms

I created a grid view application and outside of my template I have a Add new row button. When i add a new row , it gets placed with an Edit and delete button. What I'm trying to do is when I click the add new row button, i want it to open the new row in editing mode, so no blank rows can be added with empty information. So basically if I add a new row and dont input information it wont be created.

If I need to be more thorough on my explanation please ask.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What platform is this on - Web, Winforms or WPF?  And more importantly, what have you tried so far?  Your question doesn't suggest much effort on your part to solve the problem, which won't typically garner much response.

Comment: @MichaelYounani - you just need the index of the newly added row and set the `EditIndex` property, see my answer.

Comment: Hey Dan, I posted what ive done so far, sorry for coming off to vague. The button is placed outside of the grideview in a footer templete as you could see on the source page since its a gridview. Im basically trying to avoid adding blank rows into the database, i rather have the click open up the row in editing mode.

Comment: @MichaelYounani - see my edit I just made.

Comment: oh i didnt see that, thank you so much jonH!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out the problem on my own. It works perfect now. I as well changedup the database but I'm providing my code. Im sure there is an easier way but this was the best I could do: If you guys can provide inputs on an easier way I would appreciate it.

```
protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "Insert") //- this is needed to explain that the INSERT command will only work when INSERT is clicked
        {
            gv.DataBind();

            DataTable d = dbcon.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM CIS.CIS_TRANS ORDER BY ID DESC", "ProjectCISConnectionString");

            string transCode = "", fundCode = "", BSA_CD = "", DP_TYPE = "";

            if (d.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                transCode = d.Rows[0]["TRANS_CD"].ToString();
                fundCode = d.Rows[0]["FUND_CD"].ToString();
                BSA_CD = d.Rows[0]["BSA_CD"].ToString();
                DP_TYPE = d.Rows[0]["DP_TYPE"].ToString();

                if (transCode.Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    dbcon.Execute("INSERT INTO CIS.CIS_TRANS (TRANS_CD) VALUES('')", "ProjectCISConnectionString");

                    gv.DataBind();
                }
            }

            gv.EditIndex = gv.Rows.Count - 1;

        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "Cancel")
        {
            DataTable d = dbcon.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM CIS.CIS_TRANS ORDER BY ID DESC", "ProjectCISConnectionString");

            string transCode = "";

            if (d.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                transCode = d.Rows[0]["TRANS_CD"].ToString();

                if (transCode.Trim().Length == 0)
                {
                    dbcon.Execute(string.Format("DELETE CIS.CIS_TRANS WHERE ID = '{0}'", d.Rows[0]["ID"]), "ProjectCISConnectionString");

                    gv.DataBind();
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

This is fairly simple, once you add the row:

You need to set the edit index of the newly added row:

`gv.EditIndex = gv.Rows.Count-1;`

## Edit for OP

This is dirty code, I am just showing you what I mean and whipped it up fairly quickly.
Assume a gridview called GridView1 on your page:

```
namespace HelpSO3
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        List<string> t = new List<string>();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                string s = "hi";
                t.Add(s);
                GridView1.DataSource = t;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                Session["MyList"] = t;
            }
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            t = (List<string>)Session["MyList"];
            t.Add("Another String");
            GridView1.DataSource = t;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.EditIndex = GridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            Session["MyList"] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

So the Button1_Click event adds a new row with the value "Another String" then we bind the grid view and set the `EditIndex` value to the newest row and rebind.  Its that simple.

In your case your code would become:

```
 protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Insert") //- this is needed to explain that the INSERT command will only work when INSERT is clicked
        {
            dbcon.Execute("INSERT INTO PROJ_ASP (TRANS_CD) VALUES('')", "ProjectASPConnectionString");

            gv.DataBind();
            gv.EditIndex = gv.Rows.Count-1;
            gv.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

Comment: @MichaelYounani I assume you have some sort of method of adding a new row correct?  Once you add the new row (I assume you are adding to the bottom of a gridview correct?)  If so you then set the edit index of the gridview to the count of rows - 1 (as the index is 0 based).  So you would add this piece of code right after the event that adds a new row.

Comment: Yes the new rows get placed at the bottom of the grid view. You could see my add a new row code in the application above, and I'm still a little confused on how place it. I dont have it based at zero.

Comment: ok since they get placed at the bottom `gv.Rows.Count` returns the count of rows and you subtract one from it as the index is 0 based so instead of 1-5 (5 items) you have 0-4 (5 items).  You do this after you insert the row: `gv.EditIndex = gv.Rows.Count-1;`

Comment: @MichaelYounani - I edited it to show you a simple example, don't use this code as it is rotten, but it gets the point across.

Comment: thank you so much jon! I now got it to work, but when I click cancel the row remains and is still empty, is there a way around that. SOrry for  buggin you.

Comment: @MichaelYounani - this is very simple, you need to handle the cancel event and set the `gv.editindex=-1;`, that is set the editindex property to -1.  This signifies no edit is to be made.  I definately recommend you research and get a book or google gridview edit event to understand how gridviews work in asp.net.

Comment: hey i added protected void gv_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e) { //Reset the edit index. gv.EditIndex = gv.Rows.Count - 1; //Bind data to the GridView control. gv.DataBind(); } and also added OnRowCancelingEdit="gv_RowCancelingEdit" but i still get same issue. I edited in my orginial post under your edit so you could see. Thank you